# Why ng-value and value attribute of input element hold different values

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

The input field value doesn't get the assigned ng-value.The dragItms object holds the value to be bound for the given col key.
When isSaveTemplt = true, collection and columns gets updated after api call.
The functionality that I implement is such that dragItems object changes on clicking tabs and the said api is called for getting the data for tbody element.

```
<th ng-if="isSaveTemplt && collection.length>0 && columns.length>0" ng- 
repeat="col in columns track by $index">
                <input class="filterStyle" type="search"  placeholder="search 
by {{col | translate}}" st-search="{{col}}"  ng-value={{dragItms[col]}} />
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question clearly, Maybe more code and explanation is needed. Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to comment. But what I feel is the issue of using `ng-if`. Whenever `ng-if` is used it creates a child scope. So any element inside has a different scope. To access parent scope use `$parent`. So you access will be something like this `{{$parent.dragItms[col]}}`. `$parent` is parent scope.